# MonoRail - "Unexpected item on the stack" Error

Tags: castle-monorail

Anyone seen this MonoRail error before and know what it means?

**Unexpected item on the stack: found UCampus.Core.Models.Nested.Hours, expecting UCampus.Core.Models.Business**

I'm saving a Business object when this error occurs, Hours is a child of a child of Business.

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Hours class it for some reason was overriding the GetHashCode method and that was causing this peculiar exception. Any idea why they would've been overriding GetHashCode??

```
//public override int GetHashCode()
        //{
        //    unchecked
        //    {
        //        return (GetHours(Open) * 397) ^ GetHours(Close);
        //    }
        //}
```